# Magento 2.1 loop through CMS pages

Tags: magento-2.1, cms, cms-pages

I created a custom attribute in the ui_components of the cms_pages.  The custom attributes shows up in the admin section, saves to the database and can be seen on the front side of the website.  The name of the attribute is special_page and has a datatype of Boolean.

I now want to create a cms block that will loop through all of the cms pages and return links to pages where the special_page attribute is set to true (1) and the pages is set to active for the particular store.